# Windows 7 Very Slow Installation and Running

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation

I had a hard drive crash on my desktop earlier in the year and I decided to get a 1TB Hard Drive to restore my computer. However, when I started to install Windows7 on it not only did the installation itself become super laggy. This meaning it took over 8 hours to install and over an hour and a half to just get to the point where I can select my hard drive. At each of the screens the mouse lagged horribly every time I went to move it. When windows 7 finally installed on my computer it was terribly slow. The CPU was maxed at 100% at all times. What could be causing this/how can I fix it?

Comment: Test your hardware. Start with the hard drive, then the power supply.

Comment: @RandolphWest the thing is, I just installed a new Hard Drive and a New Powersupply. How would I test them?

Comment: A local computer shop will have the right tools for testing your hardware. If you've already replaced the PSU and hard drive, you may have a faulty motherboard.

Comment: Could it be a cooling issue?

Comment: Unlikely, with what you've described.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing just happened to me.  I ran the diagnostic software from my hard drive manufacturer's website (Seagate in my case - SeaTools is their free utility) and let it run a "long test".  It found plenty of errors, even though the hard drive was brand new.  Sometimes you just get a bad drive.  I ran to the local store and bought a different Seagate and Windows installed so fast I could hardly believe it.

Comment: I too suspect its a bad drive, with many faulty sectors and Windows is getting bogged down doing retries.  Unfortunately, Windows keeps this information a secret.  But check the event log anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a AMD system, you should be able to set the width of Hyper Transport (it's named HT sometimes), set it to 8. If that doesn't help, set HT Speed to 1x.

The other thing that may be causing this is enabled floppy if there's none installed in the system, to fix this go to BIOS and set Drive A to `None`.

If that's an Intel system, you may also try to disable SpeedStep.